# Straight lines as the shortest lenght curves between two points

Tags: differential-geometry, normed-spaces, curves

It is a known fact (and it has been discussed several times here on MSE) that if $p, q$ are points of $\mathbf{R}^n$ and $\sigma$ is a (piecewise $\mathcal{C}^1$, rectifiable) curve connecting them, then $$l(\sigma)\ge |q-p|$$ and if $\sigma$ is a segment of a straight line equality holds. But is the converse true? If $\sigma$ is a (piecewise $\mathcal{C}^1$) curve connecting $p$ and $q$ satisfying $$l(\sigma)=|q-p|,$$ is it true that $\sigma$ is (up to diffeomorphism) a straight line?

Please notice that I am referring only to $\mathbf{R}^n$ with its standard (Euclidean) norm, no Riemannian metrics or submanifolds involved.

Comment: You can prove that by RAA.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca: this is a little too pauca... What is RAA?

Comment: [Reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum). And of course you must use the triangular inequality.

Comment: You mean something like the following: suppose $\sigma:[0, 1]\to \mathbf{R}^n$ is a curve of minimal lenght passing through a point $r$ not lying on the (image of) the segment of straight line joining $p$ and $q$, suppose $r$ is reached for $t=t_0 \in [0, 1]$. Then $l(\sigma)=\int_0^{t_0}+\int_{t_0}^1 \ge |r-p| + |q-r|\ge |q-p|$... I would like to have strict inequality

Comment: Inequality IS strict if $r$ is not on segment $pq$ ([triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)). See the answer by Hagen.

Comment: How does one prove such a fact?

Comment: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI20.html

Comment: Well yes, in Euclidean geometry, but I am doing differential geometry, I am working in a different axiomatic context.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb R^n$ is your curve, then $l(\sigma)$ is defined as supremum of all $|\sigma(t_1)-\sigma(t_0)|+|\sigma(t_2)-\sigma(t_1)|+\cdots +|\sigma(t_n)-\sigma(t_{n-1})|$ over all tuples $(t_0,\ldots, t_n)$ with $0= t_0<t_1\ldots <t_n=1$.

Now suppose that for some $t^*\in[0,1]$, $\sigma(t^*)$ is not on $pq$. Then $$l(\sigma)\ge |\sigma(t^*)-p|+|q-\sigma(t^*)|>|p-q|.$$

Comment: Why is the last inequality strict?